# Use awk to Modify the Nth field after a specific pattern

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to use awk to change the color of cells in an HTML table.  Ideally, I would be able to use awk to locate the Nth instance (a variable passed from earlier in the script) of "tg-6k2t" after "Bob" and change the color code to "tg-b5xm".  This is a giant HTML table with many different people's names.

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">Bob</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>    
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
</tr>
```

My desired output would be

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">Bob</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-b5xm"></td>    
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an `Awk` statement as follows,

```
awk -v count=6 '/"tg-6k2t".*Bob/{x=count}x--==1{sub(/tg-6k2t/,"tg-b5xm")}1' file
```

which generates the output as below, meaning the 6th line *from* the line matching `Bob`, change the variable to your convenience.

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">Bob</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-b5xm"></td>
</tr>
```